# Were Charlie Harper's jingles real?

Tags: two-and-a-half-men

In the sitcom, Two and a Half Men, Charlie composes jingles for actual products, like cereal, Pepsi etc. And even sometimes for shows on TV like Oshikuru. Some of them are really catchy and you get a sense it should be used in the real world. Were his jingles made by someone else in the real world and used on products, and later adopted in the sitcom **or** was it made just for use in the sitcom and not in the real world?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say they're fake and created for the show.

[IMDB Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369179/trivia) states:

> Charlie Sheen does not play the piano on the show. He is dubbed by
>   composer Grant Geissman, who plays offstage while Sheen fakes it on a
>   dead keyboard. ***With composer Dennis C. Brown, Geissman also writes the
>   music for the jingles Sheen's character creates.***

However, as with a lot of their trivia, it doesn't actually cite any sources to back this up.

The musicians for the show, as stated above, [are](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369179/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast):

> Series Music by
>   Dennis C. Brown   ... (234 episodes, 2003-2014)
>   Grant
>   Geissman  ... (234 episodes, 2003-2014)

It's well known that Geissman, along with Lorre, composed the theme song for the show. I would argue it stands to reason that Geissman, along with the other musician, composes the jingles for the show.

I would base this on a few things, including: a) the jingles not appearing to exist anywhere *other* than in the show, and b) the jingles are just a standard part of the *music* of the show and thus udner the domains of its two musicians.